# CGAffineTransform not animating within animation block

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to get a view to increase its scale with a spring to it when it appears (using the `loadResultsView()` function below), but whenever I run this, no animation occurs. The view just ends up in the result state defined in the animation block. I have tried using frame values instead of constraints on the view and the same thing occurs. Why would this be happening?

```
class ResultsModalViewController: UIViewController {

    let resultsView: ResultsView = {
        let nibArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ResultsView", owner: self, options: nil)
        let resultsView = nibArray?.first as! ResultsView

        resultsView.restaurant = YelpSearchController.shared.pickRandomRestaurant()

        resultsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        resultsView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        return resultsView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.30)

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bgViewTapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


        loadResultsView()
    }

    func loadResultsView() {

        self.view.addSubview(resultsView)

        self.resultsView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.resultsView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            resultsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            resultsView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            resultsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
            ])
    }

    @objc func bgViewTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called before the view is shown, try moving the animation to `viewDidAppear`

Comment: That was it koen, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by putting the `loadResultsView()` into the `viewWillAppear()` method instead of `viewDidLoad()`. Thanks to @Koen for pointing out that `viewDidLoad()` is called before the view appears.

```
class ResultsModalViewController: UIViewController {

    let resultsView: ResultsView = {
        let nibArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ResultsView", owner: self, options: nil)
        let resultsView = nibArray?.first as! ResultsView

        resultsView.restaurant = YelpSearchController.shared.pickRandomRestaurant()

        resultsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        resultsView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        return resultsView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bgViewTapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.30)
        loadResultsView()
    }

    func loadResultsView() {

        self.view.addSubview(resultsView)

        self.resultsView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.resultsView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            resultsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            resultsView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            resultsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
            ])
    }

    @objc func bgViewTapped() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a height constraint

```
resultsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
```

then animate in

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.30)
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bgViewTapped))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    setupResultsView()
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   animateResultsView()
}

func setupResultsView() {
    self.view.addSubview(resultsView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        resultsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        resultsView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
        resultsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
        resultsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        ])
}
func animateResultsView() {
    self.resultsView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)            
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {          
        self.resultsView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that the view shows up on screen briefly at its regular size, then does the animation. However, I did resolve it by simply calling my `loadResultsView()` in `viewDidAppear()` or `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`